# Most frequent observation per row with two ranked tie-breakers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset in Excel where i would like a formula to find the most frequent observation (from column B to column F) for each row. However, if there are any ties there are two tie-breakers, ranked in the following order: The first tie-breaker is, that if the number 4 is tied as the most frequent observations in any row the result in that row should be 4. The second tie-breaker is that if there is a tie (where 4 is not tied for the most frequent observation) it should show the value in Column G.

In the picture below I have made a rough sketch of (to the left) the data I have now and (to the right) the outcome i want.

Picture of dataset:
[image]

What formula would I need to write, in order to get the result i would like?

Thanks in advance,

Anders

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
=IF(ISNA(MODE.MULT(MyData)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(4,MyData,0)),Fruit,4),IF(ISERR(INDEX(MODE.MULT(MyData),2)),MODE.MULT(MyData),IF(ISNA(MATCH(4,MODE.MULT(MyData),0)),Fruit,4)))
```

entered as an array formula `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`.

Here `MyData` is a placeholder for a row of data. In your example, `MyData` will be a single row from columns B-F; for case A, MyData={1,1,1,1,2}. `Fruit` is a placeholder the corresponding value from column G. You can replace `MyData` with `B2:F2` and `Fruit` with `G2` then copy and paste to other locations.

Here's how it works. The formula uses Excel's `MULT.MODE` function, which returns as many mode values as there are in the data.

`MULT.MODE` returns `N/A` when there are no repeated elements in `MyData`. This is the situation for your cases D and E. This means there is an N-way tie, so we need to apply the tie breaking rules. This is done by using the `MATCH` function to see if 4 is found in `MyData`; if it is, return 4, otherwise return `Fruit`.

If `MyData` has repeated elements, `MULT.MODE` returns an array containing the mode or modes found. If there is no tie, `MULT.MODE` returns a single element, otherwise the array will have at least two elements. To test for ties, we attempt access to the 2nd element of the array with use `INDEX(MULT.MODE(MyData),2)`. This will throw an error if there is no tie.

If there is no tie, detect the resulting error with `ISERR`. With no tie, we return the result of `MULT.MODE`.

If there is a tie, no error occurs. In that case, we use `MATCH` to look for 4 in the results of `MULT.MODE`. If 4 is found, we return 4; if not return `Fruit`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

@xidgel: This is a great answer, but you'll also have to account for the case where all observations are the same.

```
=IF(ISNA(MODE.MULT(MyData)),
    IF(ISNA(MATCH(4,MyData,0)),Fruit,4), 
    IF(ROWS(MODE.MULT(MyData))<2, 
    IF(AND(COUNTIF(MyData,"<>"&MODE.MULT(MyData))=0,MODE.MULT(MyData)<>4),Fruit,MODE.MULT(MyData)),
    IF(ISNA(MATCH(4,MODE.MULT(MyData),0)),Fruit,4)))
```

entered as an array formula `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.`